# Convert string to 2 column matrix - R

Tags: r

I have a string in this format X1 Y1; X2 Y2; … Xn Yn representing numbers . How can I convert it to a matrix in this format?

```
int [1:n, 1:2]
X1 Y1
X2 Y2
....
Xn Yn
```

Code:

```
string <- "11 12;20 21;34 35; 44 55; 66 77; 88 99"
mtx <- as.integer(do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(string, "\\s*;\\s*")[[1]], "\\s+")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
vec <- c("X1 Y1", "X2 Y2", "Xn Yn")
do.call(rbind, strsplit(vec, "\\s+"))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "X1" "Y1"
# [2,] "X2" "Y2"
# [3,] "Xn" "Yn"
```

For the whole string,

```r
string <- "X1 Y1;X2 Y2;Xn Yn"
do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(string, "\\s*;\\s*")[[1]], "\\s+"))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "X1" "Y1"
# [2,] "X2" "Y2"
# [3,] "Xn" "Yn"
```

- I use `"\\s*;\\s*"` (literal semi-colon with surrounding blank space) in case there are or may be spaces around the semi-colons that we are not interested in preserving;
- I use `"\\s+"` (one or more blank-space) in case it could be `"X1  Y1"` (two spaces).

---

With your updated `string` and a slight update to code in my comment:

```r
string <- "11 12;20 21;34 35; 44 55; 66 77; 88 99"
mtx <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(string, "\\s*;\\s*")[[1]], "\\s+"))
mtx <- array(as.integer(mtx), dim=dim(mtx))
mtx
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   11   12
# [2,]   20   21
# [3,]   34   35
# [4,]   44   55
# [5,]   66   77
# [6,]   88   99
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can I change the output matrix to be numeric although the string is char representing numbers?

Comment: Do you mean remove the `X` and `Y`, and retain just the numbers? Your question says nothing about that, please work on making it ***reproducible*** to include expected output (numbers vs strings?) and any code you've attempted (if any).

Comment: What I mean that `string <- c("11 12;20 21;34 35")` is something like that

Comment: If you use `mtx <- do.call(rbind, ...)`, then just do `mtx <- as.integer(mtx)` or `mtx <- as.numeric(mtx)`. (If that isn't what you're looking for, *please* update your question with relevant information.)

Comment: I update the question as your recommended but the code is not working fine. Any idea why?